# Filtrar datos por dia y mes laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo una tabla de registro con un campo nodo_ids. Los cuales necesito saber a cuantos de esos registros tomaron en cada día por id. Y tambien que se agrupen por mes. 
Es decir así:

```
Fecha     Punto 1 Punto 2 Punto 3 Total
1/02/2019    50      40     30     120
2/02/2019    10      10     10     30

Fecha     Punto 1 Punto 2 Punto 3 Total
Octubre     200     100     50     350
Noviembre   40      60     24      124
```

Cada id es un punto y el resultado de la consulta seria:

```
0 => {#488 ▼
+"nodo_id": 407
+"fecha": "2019-07-16 15:02:29"}



public function registroFecha()
    {
        $idsNodo = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT nodo_id,fecha FROM registro'));
        $meses = array();
        $nodos_array = array();
        foreach ($idsNodo as $nodo) {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                $dataFecha = DB::table('registro')->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $i)->count();
                array_push($meses, $dataFecha);
                if ($nodo->nodo_id === 401) { }
                if ($nodo->nodo_id === 402) { }
                if ($nodo->nodo_id === 403) { }
                if ($nodo->nodo_id === 404) { }
                if ($nodo->nodo_id === 405) { }
                if ($nodo->nodo_id === 406) { }
                if ($nodo->nodo_id === 407) { }
                if ($nodo->nodo_id === 408) { }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nos compartes tu consulta por favor

Comment: Podrías por favor agregar el código completo que estás utiizando?

Comment: Ya agrege el codigo